# Algolia instantsearch.js - Centre list of past & future entries on 'today'

Tags: jquery, algolia

I have an index that includes past and future entries. Is there a way that I could centre the front-end output on 'today'? I.e., the initial view would start on pagination page 6 if there are 5 pages of entries with dates in the past. I'm using Algolia's instantsearch.js for the ui.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do that with only the current pagination widget: page 5 out of 10 may or may not be the middle.

But if you are sure page 5 is the middle then just select page 5 when initializing instantsearch.js, [using searchParameters option](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#initialization).

If you cannot do that, what I would do is create a [custom pagination widget](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch.js/documentation/#custom-widgets) that would:

- filter entries to select only "todays" entries first: using a numeric filter with the [options.helper](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-helper-js#numeric-facets)
- show a previous button that would change the numeric filter to select past entries
- show a next button that would change the numberic filter to select future entries

Comment: Right - the 'today' page number will constantly be changing as entries are updated, so I won't be able to initialize on a specific static page number. I like your custom pagination suggestion so I will dig in to that. Thanks for the help.